# .htaccess not working for directory

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to redirect

```
www.example.com/directory -> www.example.com/index.php?str=directory
```

I am using

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^directory$ index.php?str=directory [L]
```

It is not working (File not found)

However if I try to redirect anything like `directory.whatever` it works perfectly. (works for anything with a dot after "`directory`")

Example:

```
www.example.com/directory.whatever -> www.example.com/index.php?str=directory


RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^directory.whatever$ index.php?str=directory [L]
```

Works fine.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Directory is a directory not a file so you should have a slash at the end.

`RewriteRule ^directory/(.*)$ index.php?str=directory [L]`

Comment: Same thing... File not found.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^directory$ index.php?str=directory [L]
```